# Viewing graph api via url not showing data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have been watching some tutorials about the facebook graph API, and one of the things in the video is to simply navigate to http://graph.facebook.com/youtube
and it should display a json response of their facebook likes etc. This is said to work without an access token?

But this doesn't seem to work, i get the following response -

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "DoY144sSuti"
   }
}
```

Has something changed that you will need to always need an access token just to see peoples data, eg how many likes a page has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has something changed that you will need to always need an access token just to see peoples data, eg how many likes a page has?

Yes. Since API v2.0, all API calls (with the profile picture redirect being the exception) need to use an access token.

Public data about public pages can be accessed using an app access token; if the page is not public it needs a user access token for a user that can see the page, or a page access token. (More about the different types of token here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

> This is said to work without an access token?

Then that tutorial is simply outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need the access token in order to view that Jason data in URL .

try this Instead :
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/posts?access_token={your-access- token}

You will be able to see the posts now.Hope this would help you .